# Can $\mathrm{PGL}_2$ be viewed as an affine algebraic group?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

I was just wondering whether or not it is possible to view $\mathrm{PGL}_2$ as an affine algebraic group.

Comment: Linear groups modulo their centers have linear representations on automorphisms of their (algebraic) Lie algebras by (algebraic) Ad, generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may view $PGL_{2}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ as an affine scheme given by an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^{4}_{\mathbb{Z}}$. More precisely, let $\{z_{11},z_{12},z_{21},z_{22}\}$ be coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^4$. Then $PGL_2$ is given by the distinguished open set $D(f)$ where $f=z_{11}z_{22}-z_{12}z_{21}$. The coordinate ring $\mathcal{O}(PGL_2)$ is the degree $0$ component of the graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[z_{11},z_{12},z_{21},z_{22}][f^{-1}]$.

$PGL_2$ is a group object in the category of schemes. Giving a group object is equivalent to giving a functorial group structure on $PGL_2(R)$ for each ring $R$. Observe that a map $s:Spec(R)\to PGL_2$ corresponds to the data (up to mutliplication by a unit in $R$):
 $(P,s_{11},s_{12},s_{21},s_{22})$ where $P$ is a projective $R$-module of rank $1$, $s_{ij}\in P$ such that $R\to P\otimes_R P$ given by $1\to (s_{11}s_{22}-s_{12}s_{21})$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

Given another map $t:Spec(R)\to PGL_2$ with data $(Q,t_{11},t_{12},t_{21},t_{22})$ we define the product morphism $s.t$ as the one associated to the data
$(P\otimes_R Q, w_{11},w_{12},w_{21},w_{22})$ where $w_{ij}$ are obtained from multiplying the matrix $[s_{ij}]$ with $[w_{ij}]$.

When $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a local ring we have $P=R$ and map to $PGL_2$ is just a 4 tuple $(s_{11},s_{12},s_{21},s_{22})$ with discriminant a unit. By virtue of it being a map to $PGL_2$ and in particular $\mathbb{P}^4$ it is implicit that we identify any two such tuples which differ by multiplication by $R^*=R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$. This is the classical description.

Comment: It may be worth noting that there is a map $\mathrm{GL}_2(R)/R^\times\to\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ with image the kernel of the natural map $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)\to H^1_\text{et}(\mathrm{Spec}(R),\mathbb{G}_m)=\mathrm{Pic}(R)$. In other words, the obstruction to algebraic group $\mathrm{PGL}_2$ agreeing with naive $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ is  $\mathrm{Pic}(R)$ which shows why it's ok in the local case as you've shown. This works for any $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $PGL(V)$ is a linear (affine) algebra group. For more on this you can see these notes:

https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/allcock/lag/lag14.pdf

See Theorem 7.1. Remember that $PGL(V)$ is defined as a quotient $GL(V) / \mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: What could replace your link, which is now broken?

Answer (score 0):

Using the identification $\operatorname{PGL}_2 = \operatorname{SL}_2/Z(\operatorname{SL_2})$, where $Z(\operatorname{SL_2}) = \{ \pm \operatorname{Id} \}$ is the center, we can use the adjoint representation to identify $\operatorname{PGL}_2 = \operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{SL}_2) \subseteq \operatorname{GL}(\mathfrak{sl}_2) \cong \operatorname{GL}_3$ as an algebraic subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_3$.